# Question about transcendental equation

Tags: calculus

I need to show that $f(x) = 1-e^{-2xf(x)}$ for $\lim_{x \to 1/2} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ is monotonically increasing on the intervall $[1/2, \infty[$. I can't seem to extract any information off of the limits. I know that $$f'(x) = \frac{2f(x)e^{-2xf(x)}}{1-2xe^{-2xf(x)}}.$$ But looking at curvature around 1/2 doesn't help aswell since the limit for $f''$ can't be calculated with what is given. Am I missing something?

Comment: oh god I completely missed that ty for pointing out!

Comment: One thought here: Suppose you look for the inverse function $g=f^{-1}$ first. (If $f(x)$ is monotonic, then it's certainly invertible.) Writing the independent variable now as $y\in[0,1[$, one has $y=1-e^{-2g(y)y}$ which can be solved for $g(y)$. So if you can show that that's monotonic as well, then I think you're done.

Comment: sorry if I missed smth but how exactly do u know assuming g is the inverse of f that $$y = 1-e^{-2g(y)y}?$$

Comment: If $f$ is invertible, then $y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=g(y)$. So $y=f(x)=1-e^{-2x f(x)}=1-e^{-2g(y)y}$. (This only works if $f$ is invertible.)

Comment: ah okay makes sense ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You xan work this problem making $f(x)$ explicit.
$$f(x) = 1-e^{-2xf(x)}\implies f(x)=1+\frac 1{2x}W\left(-2x\, e^{-2 x}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function.

For more legibility, I shall use $t=-2x\, e^{-2 x}$

From this
$$f(x)=1+\frac{W(t)}{2x}$$
$$f'(x)=W(t)\frac{ x t'-t (1+W(t))}{2 x^2 t(1+W(t))}$$
$$f''(t)=W(t)\frac {-x^2 W(t) (W(t)+2) t'^2+x t (W(t)+1)^2 \left(x t''-2
   t'\right)+2 t^2 (W(t)+1)^3 }{2 x^3 t^2 (1+W(t))^3 }$$